# Debian Jessie grub-install broken in some mysterious way

Tags: debian, boot, grub2

I did an `apt-get dist-upgrade` today (2016/02/01), and now my system won't boot.

The only reason I can get in at all is that there's a copy of Ubuntu installed as well, and I can boot it from the BIOS. update-grub there has reconfigured its boot loader to load the debian system correctly.

But when I try to grub-install from Debian:

```
root@dell-3537:/home/john# grub-install 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
efibootmgr: Could not set variable Boot0002: No such file or directory
efibootmgr: Could not prepare boot variable: No such file or directory
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

It looks as though it can't find the `grubx64.efi` file.
If I ask efi directly what's going on, it seems to have failed to add itself:

```
root@dell-3537:/home/john# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0005,2003,2001,2002
Boot0000* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv4 ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(MAC(ecf4bb93e02e,0)RC
Boot0001* UEFI Onboard LAN IPv6 ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1c,0)PCI(0,0)MAC(MAC(ecf4bb93e02e,0)030d3c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000RC
Boot0004* Ubuntu    HD(1,800,fa000,6edd2bfd-b6c6-46e9-9413-d332f1333788)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0005* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,800,fa000,6edd2bfd-b6c6-46e9-9413-d332f1333788)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e...............
Boot0007* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BIOS(3,500,00)................-.L.......L............................................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?